# Excel VBA: How to swap two selected cell ranges (not only two values) within the same column?

Tags: excel, range, cell, swap, vba

I would like to swap selected cell ranges within the same column without having automatically adjusted attached formulas in other columns. Those cell ranges will almost always be of unequal size.

I found a VBA code which does it for two selected cells, but im afraid that this wont help me much.

```
Sub SwapCells()
    Dim sHolder As String

    If Selection.Cells.Count = 2 Then
        With Selection
            sHolder = .Cells(1).Formula
            If .Areas.Count = 2 Then  ' Cells selected using Ctrl key
                .Areas(1).Formula = .Areas(2).Formula
                .Areas(2).Formula = sHolder
            Else                      ' Adjacent cells are selected
                .Cells(1).Formula = .Cells(2).Formula
                .Cells(2).Formula = sHolder
            End If
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Select only TWO cells to swap", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

I know that another option would be to hold 'shift' when moving the cell ranges (works perfectly fine), but then all the attached formulas will change their reference which I dont want (e.g. if I have a formula referring to cell A1, and im swapping A1 somewhere, the formula will refer to A1's new position, but I want the formula to still refer to A1).

I think another option would be to use INDIRECT("G" & ROW()) to fix it, but since its a quite resource-intensive formula, Id love to see an alternative.

On top of that, the latter two options would not allow me to use tables (which Id prefer for other reasons) because you cant swap cells in tables. This is why Id strongly prefer a VBA option.

I hope you can help me, thank you! Maybe it is only necessary to adjust the VBA code a little.

Kind regards,
Marco

EDIT: If it is significantly easier to swap two equal cell ranges (e.g. encompassing 5 cells each), then it would also be a good solution.

Comment: Have you tried using **`$`** in your formula? that should keep your formulas static

Comment: How can you swap when "cell ranges will almost always be of unequal size."?

Comment: @zac thanks for your comment, yes, sadly it wont work

Comment: @Vityata yes, you got a point there haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub SwapTwoSelectedRanges()

    Dim initialRng As Range
    Set initialRng = Selection

    If initialRng.Areas.Count <> 2 Then
        Debug.Print "Select 2 areas!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If initialRng.Areas(1).Cells.Count <> initialRng.Areas(2).Cells.Count Then
        Debug.Print "The cells should be the same number!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim intermediateRng As Variant
    intermediateRng = initialRng.Areas(1).Cells.Value2

    initialRng.Areas(1).Cells.Value2 = initialRng.Areas(2).Cells.Value2
    initialRng.Areas(2).Cells.Value2 = intermediateRng

End Sub
```

Swaping two values is considered an easy task, if you are using an intermediate value. With the ranges, there are two important checks to perform, before swapping them:

1. Are the selected areas exactly 2;
2. Is the number of cells equal in every area;
3. Then with an `intermediateRng` as a 3. variable, the swap is made;
4. This would only work, if the Areas are per column. If the selection is made per row, then the results would not be as expected;

---

Concerning the swaping of the colors, if the colors of all the cells per area  are exactly the same, this would work:

```
Dim intermediateRng As Variant
Dim intermediateClr As Variant

intermediateRng = initialRng.Areas(1).Cells.Value2
intermediateClr = initialRng.Areas(1).Cells.Interior.Color

With initialRng
    .Areas(1).Cells.Value2 = .Areas(2).Cells.Value2
    .Areas(1).Cells.Interior.Color = .Areas(2).Cells.Interior.Color

    .Areas(2).Cells.Value2 = intermediateRng
    .Areas(2).Cells.Interior.Color = intermediateClr
End With
```

However, if the colors of the cells per Area are not the same, then the easiest way is to copy+paste  the first range to a separate range and work from there.

Comment: Wow, I think this works out the way I wanted it to work from the start. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have one more thing to ask, please. I would not only like to save and return the value2 of each area, but also its filled color (each selection has a distinct color, no different ones). Is that easy to add? Ive tried to do something like .BackColor behind .value2, but I guess Im totally off there. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoMarss - take a look at the update. However, it works only with single color per area. For 2 colors per area, it is a better idea to ask a separate question, as far as the idea there is different.

Comment: thank you so much, saved my day! since the different areas are product groups which are arranged in different production sequences, one color per area is fine.

Comment: @MarcoMarss - Karma++ :)